# real-time updating screen by media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I was expecting that my web would change when screen size changes like I coded below

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 870px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 570px;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I shrank browser size, looking closely at the screen size's change with developer tool. I thought screen would be updated according to the media queries when screen size reaches the break points.

It works only once when loading the document.

What should I do to do this as a real-time? should I use some script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the rules. When browser reaches 1200px, it qualifies for all 3 rules.
http://jsfiddle.net/jonms83/5q6etqex/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.container {background-color:black;}
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 601px){
  .container {
    max-width: 870px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 570px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping min-width for max-width in the media spec:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 870px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 570px;
  }
}
```

I made a js-fiddle to demonstrate:  http://jsfiddle.net/mnva4kg4/

I added in some background color to show that it's indeed swapping definitions based on the media query.  You'll have to resize the display area to see it, of course.  Your HTML and other styles for `.container` will affect how it looks at different sizes.